# TFS: how to add 'text name' for priority

Tags: tfs

Is there any possibility to add text into priorities? It would be good to have values like "1 - Blocker", "2 - Critical", "3 - High", ... etc.

Attempt to change "ALLOWEDVALUES" of "Priority" field (refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority") to something like

```
    <ALLOWEDVALUES>
      <LISTITEM value="1 - Blocker" />
      <LISTITEM value="2 - Critical" />
      <LISTITEM value="3 - High" />
      <LISTITEM value="4..." />
      <LISTITEM value="5..." />
      <LISTITEM value="6..." />
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>
```

Give an error that field should be integer.

I see few options:
 1. change field type to string
 2. create a separate custom field "MyPriority" with 'string' type.

Could you please advise what is the best option (from long term usage perspective)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot change the type of an existing field. What I did in the past is adding a new field which is shown on the form. Then Add some logic to the field to copy

Add the following text to the FIELDS section

```
  <FIELD name="My Priority" refname="My.Priority" type="String" reportable="dimension">
    <REQUIRED />
    <ALLOWEDVALUES>
      <LISTITEM value="1 - Blocker" />
      <LISTITEM value="2 - Critical" />
      <LISTITEM value="3 - High" />
      <LISTITEM value="4..." />
      <LISTITEM value="5..." />
      <LISTITEM value="6..." />
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>
    <DEFAULT from="value" value="3 - High" />
  </FIELD>
```

And change the default priority field to

```
  <FIELD name="Priority" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority" type="Integer" reportable="dimension">
    <REQUIRED />
    <ALLOWEDVALUES>
      <LISTITEM value="1" />
      <LISTITEM value="2" />
      <LISTITEM value="3" />
      <LISTITEM value="4" />
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>
    <DEFAULT from="value" value="2" />
    <WHEN field="My.Priority" value="1 - Blocker">
      <COPY from="value" value="1" />
    </WHEN>
    <WHEN field="My.Priority" value="2 - Critical">
      <COPY from="value" value="2" />
    </WHEN>
    <WHEN field="My.Priority" value="3 - High">
      <COPY from="value" value="3" />
    </WHEN>
    <WHEN field="My.Priority" value="4...">
      <COPY from="value" value="4" />
    </WHEN>
  </FIELD>
```

Locate the Priority in the FORMS section and change it to use the My.Priority:

```
  <Control Type="FieldControl" FieldName="My.Priority" Label="Pri&amp;ority:" LabelPosition="Left" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can change type of an existing field. So 2nd option is the only option. In my company I have customized work item types extensively and have used quite a few custom fields. It works well. Having said that, you will need to load your new field with existing priority data (if there is any).

A simple stored proc to copy data from Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority field to "New custom field" should do the job. WorkItemsLatestUsed table should be the only table touched for this purpose.